# AngularJS - How to get the name of the current HTML template file for the ui-view?

Tags: html, angularjs, uiview

My app shows an HTML page with multiple views, and each view can be conditionally built from multiple HTML templates.

I want to edit each HTML file and add a few lines at the top, something like

```
<div ng-if="showFileNames”>
   <hr>
        <p>Start of file {{how do I get the file name}}</p>
   <hr>
</div>
```

And maybe the same at the footer.

Thus, by setting `$scope. showFileNames` to `true`, I could switch the display of file names on/off and see how my page is actually composed (is this clear, or should I add some ascii art?).

I ***could*** just hard code `{{how do I get the file name}}` in each file, but doing it dynamically means that I can more easily add the code to each file, plus it guards against files being renamed.

Can it be done? If so, how?

---

[Update] I just realized that the question didn't explain well enough. Sorry.

I need to stress that part where I said

> each view can be conditionally built from multiple HTML templates

While the view is state based, its contents are built from different `<ng-include>` files, based on data.

So, state A might include A.html, but, based on the data, that view might `<ng-include>` B.html, C.html and E.html, ***or*** it might `<ng-include>` F.html, G.html and H.htFl - and I want to show the file name of each at the head & foot of the part of the view shown by  each file

Comment: Are you using `ui-view`?

Comment: I am, indeed. Hmm, I wonder why the close vote? As usual, we will never know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: You may have templates loaded with `ui-view` and `ng-include`. The example given bottom of this answer has a nice generic `directive` to return the corresponding template name even though if you nested `ui-view` and `ng-include` together. Click through "*Home*", "*About*" and "*Named View*" link inside "About".

Few theory goes below,

If you use `ui-view` then you can try this with `$state.current.templateUrl` as below.

```
<div ng-if="showFileNames”>
   <hr>
        <p>Start of file {{$state.current.templateUrl}}</p>
   <hr>
</div>
```

The above will work if you had defined your `state` as below,

```
.state('state1', {
  url: '/state1',
  templateUrl: 'partials/state1.html'
  controller: 'State1Ctrl'
})
```

But if you had defined this as `named views` as below,

```
$stateProvider
  .state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters': {
        templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for filters view ... }
      }
      }
    }
  })
```

Then, better you can have a method assigned with the `$rootScope` as below and pass the `$state.current.views` from the html to the function.

```
$rootScope.getTemplate = function(view) {
   var keys = Object.keys(view);
   if(keys.length === 0) return '';

   return view[keys[0]].templateUrl;
};
```

and the html,

```
<div ng-if="showFileNames”>
   <hr>
        <p>Start of file {{getTemplate($state.current.views)}}</p>
   <hr>
</div>
```

But you can have a look at the below generic `directive` which covers `ui-view`, nested ui-view, named ui-view and `ng-include` and even a bit of complex nesting with ui-view and ng-include.

**Generic `directive` with an example page**

Click through "*Home*", "*About*" and "*Named View*" link inside "About"

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'TestController'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'TestController'
      })
      .state('about.named', {
        url: '/named',
        views: {
           'named': {
             templateUrl: 'named.html',
             controller: 'TestController'
           }
        }
      });
    }
]);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  
});

app.directive('templateName', ['$state', function($state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var templateName = $state.current.templateUrl;
      var includesParent = $(element).closest('[ng-include]');
      if(includesParent && includesParent.length > 0) {
        if(includesParent.find('[ui-view]').length === 0) {
           templateName = scope.$eval(includesParent.attr('ng-include'));
        }
      }
      
      if(!templateName && $state.current.views) {
        var uiViewParent = $(element).closest('[ui-view]');
        var viewName = $state.current.views[uiViewParent.attr('ui-view')];
        if(viewName) {
          templateName = viewName.templateUrl;
        }
      }
      
      element.html(templateName);
    }
  };
}]);


angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-include="'nav.html'">
</nav>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
    <div ui-view></div>

</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <h3>Home Page</h3>
  <p>Start of file: <span template-name></span></p>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
  <h3>About Page<h3>
  <p>Start of file: <span template-name></span></p>
  <div ng-include="'aboutUs.html'"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="aboutUs.html">
  <h3>About us<h3>
  <p>Start of file: <span template-name></span></p>
  <a ui-sref="about.named">Named View</a>
  <div ui-view="named"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="named.html">
  <h3>Named View<h3>
  <p>Start of file: <span template-name></span></p>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="nav.html">
  <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">Start of file: <span template-name></span></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I am at work, but will test this as soon as I get home. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Mawg Yes it will

Comment: @Mawg I have updated the answer for both `simple view` and `named view` as I am not sure which view you have used :-)

Comment: Oops! I have just realised that this does not answer me. It works for views, but not for files which are `ng-include`d from those views :-(

Comment: Yes for 'ng-include' it will be different. You can have a directive for this. Let me update it shortly

Comment: That why I actually asked you in the comment on the question :-)

Comment: I ***do** apologize. I have updated the question to make it clearer. Yours is a great solution - but not for me :-(

Comment: No worries, I have an idea to make it more generic for all the three cases, I will update it shortly as I am out at the moment :-)

Comment: You can have a look at the above updated answer  which has a nice generic `directive` with an example to prove this. Click through "Home", "About" and "Named View" link inside "About". Also, you can see the template name on the `nav` bar. Hope it will solve you :-)

Comment: If the `about.htnl` page would `ng-include` both `uk.html` and `usa.html`, which don't have states, but are just parts of the page, would we see their names too, at the start of that part of the view which they contribute?

Comment: Yes they will show. You can see its showing `aboutUs.html` in the same way if you go  to the about page. It didn't have any state, just a `ng-include`

Comment: If you look at the template `<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">` above it just has `<div ng-include="'aboutUs.html'"></div>` inside this without any state

Comment: Then I will certainly award the answer. You have done some excellent work. This is the soft of thing that makes S.O great!

Comment: I guess that I only have to add the directive code ot my app?

Comment: Yes you can add a directive and use it straight away. That's it :-)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again,  but can I easilly make it conditional? Perhaps by settign a $scope variable? No problem if not, I cna simply un/comment it as needed

Comment: When you do like this with the directive `<p>Start of file: <span template-name></span></p>`, you can add `ng-if="showFileNames”` as in your question, so it will come like this, `<p ng-if="showFileNames>Start of file: <span template-name></span></p>`